# Wordpress page layout/template

Tags: wordpress, templates

Ive successfully created my first wp-theme but I'm having a little problem, I'm sure its lack of experience.

Heres my problem;
I created my theme based on my index.html in dreamweaver. Now I'm trying to add a new page (About) but the thing is that the content layout of my index.html and my about.html are not the same.

Can I create a template so that I can pick which areas I want to keep and which I dont need for each page in wordpress?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, here's the codex link for custom page templates;

http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Custom_Page_Templates

You create a new template and make it look totally different to the default one if you want, then apply that template to the page in the backend like the shot below;

[image]

Comment: seems like I'm missing that tab on my dashboard, how do I add one?

Comment: The template tab won't be there unless there is actually another template to apply.  If 'Page Attributes' is missing altogether for some reason then click on Screen Options in the top top right and place a check next to that option.

Comment: the page attributes are there, I totally missed your link about the custom templates.. Thanx I will check that out.

Comment: No problem, glad to help - enjoy the creative freedom! :)

Answer (score 2):

You should add

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Name of your template
*/
?>
```

So is recognized as a template, save the file in .php